# When getting my emails from my pop3 account the progressBar percentages is getting to 99% why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What I get is 99% and on the label8 I see 1 and not 0 and the progressBar should get to 100%.

This is the backgroundworker dowork and progresschanged and completed events:

```
private int numberofallmessages = 0;
        private int countMsg = 0;

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
            PopClient.Connect("mail.bezeqint.net", 110, false);
            PopClient.Authenticate("mymeila", "mypass",
                OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

            int messageCount = PopClient.GetMessageCount();
            numberofallmessages = messageCount;
            allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
                int nProgress = (messageCount - i + 1) * 100 / messageCount;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, PopClient.GetMessageCount().ToString() + "/" + i);
            }
            PopClient.Disconnect();        
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            label8.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            label8.Visible = true;
            lstMail.Items.Add(allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject);
            countMsg += 1;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (closingForm)
                this.Close();
        }
```

In the constructor I start the backgroundworker and set the progressBar (pbt) to 0%.

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
pbt.Text = "0%";
```

This is the progressBar code:
In top of form1:

```
ProgressBarWithText pbt = new ProgressBarWithText();
```

In constructor:

```
pbt.Size = new Size(216, 10);
pbt.Location = new Point(8, 312);
groupBox1.Controls.Add(pbt);
```

The ProgressBarWithText class:

```
public class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
        {
            const int WmPaint = 15;
            SizeF TextSize;
            PointF TextPos;
            bool dontpaint = false;

            public ProgressBarWithText()
            {
                this.DoubleBuffered = true;
                this.TextChanged += ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged;
                this.SizeChanged += ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged;
            }

            public override string Text
            {
                get { return base.Text; }
                set { base.Text = value; }
            }

            void RecalcTextPos()
            {
                if (this.IsDisposed == true)
                    return;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
                    return;

                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
                {
                    TextSize = graphics.MeasureString(base.Text, this.Font);
                    TextPos.X = (this.Width / 2) - (TextSize.Width / 2);
                    TextPos.Y = (this.Height / 2) - (TextSize.Height / 2);
                }
            }

            void ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RecalcTextPos();
            }

            void ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RecalcTextPos();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if (dontpaint == false)
                {
                    switch (m.Msg)
                    {
                        case WmPaint:
                            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
                                graphics.DrawString(base.Text, base.Font, Brushes.Black, TextPos.X, TextPos.Y);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                    result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

The question is if I really downloaded all the emails or there is one left? And how to change/set the code is it will get to 100% and 0 emails downloaded count?

I did a test now I changed the line:

```
int messageCount = PopClient.GetMessageCount();
```

To

```
int messageCount = 5;
```

And I see in the listView I added to the designer that there are 5 emails.
But what I see in label8 is 7011/1 7011 is the overall emails in the account but for the test I'm downloading only 5. Again it stopped on 1 not 0.
And the progressBar stopped on 80% the text is 80% but I see the green color in the progressBar moved to the end to 100%.

Why it's stopping on 1 and why I see 80%?

Comment: Suggestion: Give all your controls that you will reference outside of generated code meaningful names. It's hard to look at code and know what `label8` or `groupBox1` mean.

Comment: Did you step through the debugger at the line  `int nProgress =  ..` to ensure that `nProgress` gets to `100` and that this progress is being reported? Maybe also add a `volatile` to `private int countMsg = 0;`? Otherwise it seems there's an off-by-one in there.

Comment: Set some breakpoints in your code and examine the variable states.